# How to get JSON object length in jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

i have two JSON objects inside a JSON array as below

```
array.put(resObj);

array.put(resObjPrd);
```

i'm returning this array as a Jquery ajax response.Can anyone please explain me how can i get the length of second object using jquery?
Here is my Jquery ajax code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "fetch",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        clientidedit: clientidedit
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data[1]);

    }
});
```

Comment: _"how can i get the length of second object"_  Is `resObjPrd` an `Array` ? `data[1].length` ?

Comment: i'm getting undefined while alert(data[1].length);

Comment: _"getting undefined while alert(data[1].length)"_ Is `resObjPrd` an `Array` ?

Comment: resObjPrd and resObj are two JSON objects..and i'm adding it to a json array "array". i want to get the length of 2nd object

Comment: `Object` `{}` does not have `.length` property . Though could use `JSON.stringify()` to get string representation of `Object` , then return `.length` of stringified object

Comment: @guest271314 so how can i get the size of object ?

Comment: Try using `JSON.stringify()`, see post.

Answer (score 1):

Could use `JSON.stringify()` to retrieve string representation of `Object` , then return `.length` of stringified object

```js
var obj = {"abc":123};
var objStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(objStr.length)
```